# How can I make a user registration confirmation email secure?

Tags: php

I have written a simple PHP user system where the user submits a user name, password, and email via an html form. I hash the password and add everything to a database. In the db table there is a bit field to say whether the account is activated or not. Now the question is, what exactly do I write that creates a registration confirmation email? How do I generate a link that registers this particular user without exposing the system behind it?

This would be the wrong way

```
Please click this link to complete registration:
www.mysite.com/app/user?register=1&user=thisUser
```

What am I not thinking of here? How do I make this secure?

Comment: Use an activation code.

Comment: `if is set and not empty{...} else{ kick them out }` along with a prepared statement.

Comment: Question's unclear. Oh, and if we were (equally) unclear or you need more info, don't be shy and step in at any time ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate a random personal key for every user and insert it into the database. Than the confirm-link could look like this:

```
Click here to confirm:
 http://yourwebsite.com/?confirm=1362172183
```

Than you can check if there's set a get value of 'confirm' and if it exists you can delete the entry in the database and insert something like 'confirmed'. Then you can check if it was confirmed.